# Resolve gradle build script dependencies

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-dependencies

How to check resolve dependencies of build gradle script. For example I have plugin1 and plugin2, how I can figure out what dependencies pull both of them, and each separately?

Is there any parameter to print out this info?

Answer (score 3):

the latest gradle version comes with the `buildEnvironment` task that does exactly what you need. you can simply run

```
gradle buildEnvironment
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gradle dependencies` to get the full list.  If your only interesting in a specific module then you can use `gradle app:dependencyInsight --dependency com.google.code.gson` example for `gson`

All dependency example outputs are from the project: https://github.com/JBirdVegas/external_jbirdvegas_mGerrit

Here is an example output

```
$ gradle dependencies app:dependencies
------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

No configurations
:app:dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Project :app
------------------------------------------------------------

_debugAndroidTestApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
\--- com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.1
     \--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1

_debugAndroidTestCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
\--- com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.1
     \--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1

_releaseUnitTestApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
No dependencies

_releaseUnitTestCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
No dependencies

androidJacocoAgent - The Jacoco agent to use to get coverage data.
\--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.7.4.201502262128

androidJacocoAnt - The Jacoco ant tasks to use to get execute Gradle tasks.
\--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.ant:0.7.4.201502262128
     +--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.7.4.201502262128
     |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-debug-all:5.0.1
     +--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.report:0.7.4.201502262128
     |    +--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.7.4.201502262128 (*)
     |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-debug-all:5.0.1
     \--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.7.4.201502262128

androidTestApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'androidTest' classes.
No dependencies

androidTestCompile - Classpath for compiling the androidTest sources.
No dependencies

androidTestProvided - Classpath for only compiling the androidTest sources.
No dependencies

androidTestWearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'androidTest'.
No dependencies

apk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'main' classes.
No dependencies

archives - Configuration for archive artifacts.
No dependencies

checkstyle - The Checkstyle libraries to be used for this project.
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/5.9/checkstyle-5.9.pom
\--- com.puppycrawl.tools:checkstyle:5.9
     +--- antlr:antlr:2.7.7
     +--- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:1.8.3
     +--- commons-cli:commons-cli:1.2
     \--- com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:14.0.1

compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-annotations:1.2.1
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1
+--- com.android.support:design:23.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 (*)
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4
+--- com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18
+--- com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-core:3.1.0
+--- com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-core-slh:3.1.0
+--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
+--- de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0
+--- joda-time:joda-time:2.7
+--- org.ajoberstar:gradle-git:1.1.0
|    +--- org.ajoberstar:grgit:1.1.0
|    |    +--- org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:3.7.0.201502260915-r
|    |    |    +--- com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.50
|    |    |    +--- com.googlecode.javaewah:JavaEWAH:0.7.9
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.3
|    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.1.4
|    |    |    |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
|    |    |    |    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.4
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.2 -> 1.7.7
|    |    +--- org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit.ui:3.7.0.201502260915-r
|    |    |    \--- org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:3.7.0.201502260915-r (*)
|    |    +--- com.jcraft:jsch.agentproxy.jsch:0.0.7
|    |    |    +--- com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.49 -> 0.1.50
|    |    |    \--- com.jcraft:jsch.agentproxy.core:0.0.7
|    |    +--- com.jcraft:jsch.agentproxy.pageant:0.0.7
|    |    |    +--- com.jcraft:jsch.agentproxy.core:0.0.7
|    |    |    +--- net.java.dev.jna:jna:3.4.0
|    |    |    \--- net.java.dev.jna:platform:3.4.0
|    |    +--- com.jcraft:jsch.agentproxy.sshagent:0.0.7
|    |    |    \--- com.jcraft:jsch.agentproxy.core:0.0.7
|    |    +--- com.jcraft:jsch.agentproxy.usocket-jna:0.0.7
|    |    |    +--- com.jcraft:jsch.agentproxy.core:0.0.7
|    |    |    +--- net.java.dev.jna:jna:3.4.0
|    |    |    \--- net.java.dev.jna:platform:3.4.0
|    |    +--- com.jcraft:jsch.agentproxy.usocket-nc:0.0.7
|    |    |    \--- com.jcraft:jsch.agentproxy.core:0.0.7
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7
|    \--- com.github.zafarkhaja:java-semver:0.8.0
+--- se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.6.0
+--- com.github.dmytrodanylyk.android-process-button:library:1.0.3
+--- de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.2
+--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
+--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
+--- com.anupcowkur:reservoir:2.1
|    +--- com.jakewharton:disklrucache:2.0.2
|    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4 -> 2.4
|    +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
|    \--- io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0
|         \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.4
\--- com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.5.5
     +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1 (*)
     +--- com.mikepenz:materialize:0.5.1
     +--- com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.5.0
     \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1

debugApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'debug' classes.
No dependencies

debugCompile - Classpath for compiling the debug sources.
+--- com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-runtime:1.2.1
|    +--- com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-annotations:1.2.1
|    \--- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.5
\--- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.5
```

For an example of app:dependencyInsight for `gson`

```
$ gradle app:dependencyInsight --configuration compile  --dependency com.google.code.gson

:app:dependencyInsight
com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4 (conflict resolution)
\--- compile

com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4 -> 2.4
\--- com.anupcowkur:reservoir:2.1
     \--- compile

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.018 secs
```

***EDIT:***
To get the build script dependencies I think you need a custom task... Something like this

```
task buildScriptDependencies(type: org.gradle.api.tasks.diagnostics.DependencyReportTask) {
    configurations = project.buildscript.configurations
}
```

Then you can quickly get the build script dependencies from the command line:

```
$ gradle buildScriptDependencies
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:buildSrc:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:classes UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:jar UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:compileTestGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:test UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:check UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:build UP-TO-DATE
versionCode: 2111073 versionName: 2.111.73
Applying signing plugin
Not signing release.  keyStoreFile was not defined in private.creds
Adding git task
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.3 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.3 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Adding javadoc task
Adding style task
:buildScriptDependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

classpath
+--- com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0
|    \--- com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:1.5.0
|         +--- com.android.tools.build:builder:1.5.0
|         |    +--- com.android.tools.build:builder-model:1.5.0
|         |    |    \--- com.android.tools:annotations:24.5.0
|         |    +--- com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:1.5.0
|         |    |    \--- com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:24.5.0
|         |    |         +--- com.android.tools:common:24.5.0
|         |    |         |    +--- com.android.tools:annotations:24.5.0
|         |    |         |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:17.0
|         |    |         \--- net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0
|         |    +--- com.android.tools.build:transform-api:1.5.0
|         |    |    +--- com.android.tools:annotations:24.5.0
|         |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:17.0
|         |    +--- com.android.tools:sdklib:24.5.0
|         |    |    +--- com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:24.5.0
|         |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools:common:24.5.0 (*)
|         |    |    |    +--- net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0
|         |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools:annotations:24.5.0
|         |    |    |    \--- com.intellij:annotations:12.0
|         |    |    +--- com.android.tools:dvlib:24.5.0
|         |    |    |    \--- com.android.tools:common:24.5.0 (*)
|         |    |    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4
|         |    |    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.8.1
|         |    |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.1
|         |    |    |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.1
|         |    |    |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
|         |    |    |    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.4
|         |    |    \--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.1
|         |    |         +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.1
|         |    |         \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
|         |    +--- com.android.tools:sdk-common:24.5.0
|         |    |    +--- com.android.tools:sdklib:24.5.0 (*)
|         |    |    +--- com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:1.5.0 (*)
|         |    |    \--- com.android.tools.build:builder-model:1.5.0 (*)
|         |    +--- com.android.tools:common:24.5.0 (*)
|         |    +--- com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:24.5.0
|         |    |    +--- com.android.tools:common:24.5.0 (*)
|         |    |    +--- com.android.tools:sdklib:24.5.0 (*)
|         |    |    +--- com.android.tools:sdk-common:24.5.0 (*)
|         |    |    +--- net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0
|         |    |    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4
|         |    +--- com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:24.5.0 (*)
|         |    +--- com.android.tools.jack:jack-api:0.9.0
|         |    +--- com.android.tools.jill:jill-api:0.9.0
|         |    +--- com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.0
|         |    +--- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.48
|         |    |    \--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.48
|         |    +--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.48
|         |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:5.0.3
|         |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:5.0.3
|         |    |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm:5.0.3
|         |    +--- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:3.5.2
|         |    \--- org.antlr:antlr:3.5.2
|         |         +--- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:3.5.2
|         |         \--- org.antlr:ST4:4.0.8
|         |              \--- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:3.5.2
|         +--- com.android.tools.lint:lint:24.5.0
|         |    +--- com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:24.5.0
|         |    |    +--- com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:24.5.0
|         |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools:sdk-common:24.5.0 (*)
|         |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools.build:builder-model:1.5.0 (*)
|         |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools.external.lombok:lombok-ast:0.2.3
|         |    |    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:17.0
|         |    |    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:5.0.3
|         |    |    |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:5.0.3 (*)
|         |    |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:5.0.3
|         |    |         \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:5.0.3 (*)
|         |    \--- org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:4.4.2
|         +--- com.android.tools.build:transform-api:1.5.0 (*)
|         +--- com.android.databinding:compilerCommon:1.0-rc5
|         |    +--- com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:1.0-rc5
|         |    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2
|         |    +--- com.tunnelvisionlabs:antlr4:4.5
|         |    |    +--- com.tunnelvisionlabs:antlr4-runtime:4.5
|         |    |    |    +--- org.abego.treelayout:org.abego.treelayout.core:1.0.1
|         |    |    |    \--- com.tunnelvisionlabs:antlr4-annotations:4.5
|         |    |    +--- com.tunnelvisionlabs:antlr4-annotations:4.5
|         |    |    +--- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:3.5.2
|         |    |    \--- org.antlr:ST4:4.0.8 (*)
|         |    +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
|         |    \--- com.googlecode.juniversalchardet:juniversalchardet:1.0.3
|         +--- net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:5.2.1
|         |    \--- net.sf.proguard:proguard-base:5.2.1
|         \--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.7.4.201502262128
|              \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-debug-all:5.0.1
\--- com.gradle:build-receipt-plugin:1.0

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.961 secs
```

Comment: Yep, this is usefull command, it peints fependecies for modules, sources i mean, but I try to rigure out how to print dependencies for build script, for exaple for maven plugin?

Comment: You need a custom task for the build script dependencies... see edited answer